# Numpy grouping by range of difference between elements

Tags: python, numpy, grouping

I have an array of angles that I want to group into arrays with a max difference of 2 deg between them.

eg: input:

```
angles = np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4],[4],[5],[10]])
```

output

```
('group', 1)
[[1]
 [2]
 [3]]
('group', 2)
[[4]
 [4]
 [5]]
('group', 3)
[[10]]
```

[numpy.diff](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) gets the difference of the next element from the current, I need the difference of the next elements from the first of the group

[itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) groups the elements not within a definable range

[numpy.digitize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) groups the elements by a predefined range, not by the range specified by the elements of the array.
(Maybe I can use this by getting the unique values of angles, grouping them by their difference and using that as the predefined range?)

.

My approach which works but seems extremely inefficient and non-pythonic:
(I am using *expand_dims* and *vstack* because I'm working with a 1d arrays (not just angles) but I've reduced them to simplify it for this question)

```
angles = np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4],[4],[5],[10]])

groupedangles = []
idx1 = 0
diffAngleMax = 2

while(idx1 < len(angles)):
    angleA = angles[idx1]
    group = np.expand_dims(angleA, axis=0)
    for idx2 in xrange(idx1+1,len(angles)):
        angleB = angles[idx2]
        diffAngle = angleB - angleA
        if abs(diffAngle) <= diffAngleMax:
            group = np.vstack((group,angleB))
        else:
            idx1 = idx2
            groupedangles.append(group)
            break
    if idx2 == len(angles) - 1:
        if idx1 == idx2:
            angleA = angles[idx1]
            group = np.expand_dims(angleA, axis=0)
        groupedangles.append(group)
        break

for idx, x in enumerate(groupedangles):
    print('group', idx+1)
    print(x)
```

What is a better and faster way to do this?

Comment: How many angles do you expect? Are they integer? Do they range between 0 and 360? If angles are a simplification what corresponds to 2 deg in reality?

Comment: The number of angles can vary from 5 to 500, there is no limit for how many should be in a group. They are non-integer. The range is between 0-180 so an additional step is needed to calculate from 178-0 & 179-1. When i said the arrays are simplified i meant that the array elements are 1x5: [x1,y1,x2,y2,length,angle], eg: [352.0, 18.0, 383.0, 20.0, 965.0, 176.30861401]. for the question I removed the other elements and kept only the angle for simplicity.

Comment: If the number is <= 500 sorting should be a non-issue.

Comment: I know, I said its a plus so I would be able to use the solution in the future if I do have a case that has a larger unordered array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update** Here is some Cython treatment

```
In [1]: import cython

In [2]: %load_ext Cython

In [3]: %%cython
   ...: import numpy as np
   ...: cimport numpy as np
   ...: def cluster(np.ndarray array, np.float64_t maxdiff):
   ...:     cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] flat = np.sort(array.flatten())
   ...:     cdef list breakpoints = []
   ...:     cdef np.float64_t seed = flat[0]
   ...:     cdef np.int64_t int = 0
   ...:     for i in range(0, len(flat)):
   ...:         if (flat[i] - seed) > maxdiff:
   ...:             breakpoints.append(i)
   ...:             seed = flat[i]
   ...:     return np.split(array, breakpoints)
   ...:
```

Sparsity test

```
In [4]: angles = np.random.choice(np.arange(5000), 500).astype(np.float64)[:, None]

In [5]: %timeit cluster(angles, 2)
422 µs ± 12.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Duplication test

```
In [6]: angles = np.random.choice(np.arange(500), 1500).astype(np.float64)[:, None]

In [7]: %timeit cluster(angles, 2)
263 µs ± 14.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Both tests show a significant improvement. The algorithm now sorts the input and makes a single run over the sorted array, which makes it stable O(N*log(N)).

**Pre-update**

This is a variation on seed clustering. It requires no sorting

```
def cluster(array, maxdiff):
    tmp = array.copy()
    groups = []
    while len(tmp):
        # select seed
        seed = tmp.min()
        mask = (tmp - seed) <= maxdiff
        groups.append(tmp[mask, None])
        tmp = tmp[~mask]
    return groups
```

Example:

```
In [27]: cluster(angles, 2)
Out[27]: 
[array([[1],
        [2],
        [3]]), array([[4],
        [4],
        [5]]), array([[10]])]
```

A benchmark for 500, 1000 and 1500 angles:

```
In [4]: angles = np.random.choice(np.arange(500), 500)[:, None]

In [5]: %timeit cluster(angles, 2)
1.25 ms ± 60.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [6]: angles = np.random.choice(np.arange(500), 1000)[:, None]

In [7]: %timeit cluster(angles, 2)
1.46 ms ± 37 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [8]: angles = np.random.choice(np.arange(500), 1500)[:, None]

In [9]: %timeit cluster(angles, 2)
1.99 ms ± 72.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

While the algorithm is O(N^2) in the worst case and O(N) in the best case, the benchmarks above clearly show near-linear time growth, because the actual runtime depends on the structure of your data: sparsity and the duplication rate. In most real cases you won't hit the worst case.

Some sparsity benchmarks

```
In [4]: angles = np.random.choice(np.arange(500), 500)[:, None]

In [5]: %timeit cluster(angles, 2)
1.06 ms ± 27.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [6]: angles = np.random.choice(np.arange(1000), 500)[:, None]

In [7]: %timeit cluster(angles, 2)
1.79 ms ± 117 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [8]: angles = np.random.choice(np.arange(1500), 500)[:, None]

In [9]: %timeit cluster(angles, 2)
2.16 ms ± 90.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [10]: angles = np.random.choice(np.arange(5000), 500)[:, None]

In [11]: %timeit cluster(angles, 2)
3.21 ms ± 139 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Wouldn't you increase the number of elements and keep the number of iterations the same to test time growth?

Comment: This method does exactly what I was looking for and I can use the idea to work on an array that might be pre-sorted to reduce complexity.
As an addition to my question, Is it possible to check for angles that are in the range 0-180, so that 178 is grouped with 0, and 179 with 1, aswell?

Comment: @Ta946 that would be a sparsity test (i've added these benchmarks); the tests I've uploaded earlier were duplication tests.

Comment: I'm not sure what it would be called honestly

Comment: @Ta946 Can angles exceed 180°?

Comment: no, the range is between 0-180. so that 178 is within 2 deg of 0

Comment: @Ta946 yes, you can modify the dissimilarity function to account for rollover

Comment: I think I found it. np.logical_and((tmp - seed) <= maxdiff, tmp >= (180 - maxdiff + seed))

Comment: @Ta946 I've added a new Cython solution.

Comment: Looks like i was mistaken about sorting being more computationally intensive than the algorithm.
We seem to have a similar idea for the algorithm to work with a presorted array

Comment: @Ta946 it really depends on your data. My original algorithm would be less efficient for sparse data points and highly efficient for dense data with few underlying clusters (which seems to be your case, considering that there can't be more than (180 - maxdiff) clusters in your dataset).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sorting based solution. One could try and be a bit smarter and use bincount and argpartition to avoid the sorting, but at N <= 500 it's not worth the trouble.

```
import numpy as np

def flexibin(a):
    idx0 = np.argsort(a)
    as_ = a[idx0]
    A = np.r_[as_, as_+2]
    idx = np.argsort(A)
    uinv = np.flatnonzero(idx >= len(a))
    linv = np.empty_like(idx)
    linv[np.flatnonzero(idx < len(a))] = np.arange(len(a))
    bins = [0]
    curr = 0
    while True:
        for j in range(uinv[idx[curr]], len(idx)):
            if idx[j] < len(a) and A[idx[j]] > A[idx[curr]] + 2:
                bins.append(j)
                curr = j
                break
        else:
            return np.split(idx0, linv[bins[1:]])

a = 180 * np.random.random((500,))
bins = flexibin(a)

mn, mx = zip(*((np.min(a[b]), np.max(a[b])) for b in bins))
assert np.all(np.diff(mn) > 2)
assert np.all(np.subtract(mx, mn) <= 2)
print('all ok')
```

Comment: With 1000 repetitions, for a smaller subset of elements N<1000 your method is slighty faster (Eli: 1.5s, Paul: 1.9s). But for N>10000, the time increases exponentially with N (Eli: 15.7s, Paul: 4.9s). Is that because of the sorting? I would like to test the algorithm to accept an already sorted array instead

Comment: should i just replace. idx0 = range(len(a)) & as_ = a.copy() ? Also, If i wanted to replace 2 deg with 'maxdiff' do i just replace A[idx[curr]] + maxdiff: only (aside from the assert)? what about A[idx[curr]] + 2 ?

Comment: I think your edits are correct; only, we needn't copy `a` since we do not change `as_` and I think all `2s` in the code are `maxdiff`s; I'm not 100% you can get away with `idx0` a range, if it doesn't work try making it an arange.

Comment: Re the complexity it certainly shouldn't grow exponentially; slightly super linearly yes.

Comment: i only changed idx0 to a range because of: return np.split(idx0, linv[bins[1:]]). since im not sure what is happening there

Comment: @Ta946 as Paul said, both algorithms are not exponential, they are hyper-linear under normal circumstances, but not even quadratic.

Comment: @Ta946 I just checked. `range` should work. The `split` splits `idx0` at the split points we have calculated before. If `a` is presorted, then for testing using a range is good enough. For production you would want to return `np.r_[linvl(bins), len(a)] instead and then use slices `a[bins[i]:bins[i+1]]` instead of advanced indexing.

Comment: @EliKorvigo Isn't your's linear (if with a rather large constant) since the number of groups is llimited and each of your iterations is O(n)?

Comment: @Ta946 As I said use `return np.r_[linv(bins), len(a)]` instead and then slicing. For example `mn, mx = zip(*((np.min(a[l:r]), np.max(a[l:r])) for l, r in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])))`.

Comment: @PaulPanzer it's only linear in the best case scenario. In the worst case (if there are N clusters in an array of N items) the function will run `np.min` at each iteration making it quadratic.

Comment: yea i deleted my comment because i made a mistake earlier. got it working now

Comment: @EliKorvigo Yeah but in the current setting there can be no more than `180 / 2`  clusters, right?

Comment: @PaulPanzer Yes, that is true. That's why I wrote the OP would never hit that worst case.

Comment: @PaulPanzer I've added some Cython and sorting.

Comment: @EliKorvigo Nice.